# Changing the color of output index

Tags: c++

I need to change the color of index in sorting algorithm, i am using `system(COLOR C);`, but it changes the color of all text. Need to change only  `index` color in gnomeSort

```
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std; 
//print Array
void printArray(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    cout << "Sorted sequence after Gnome sort: "; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        cout << arr[i] << " "; 
    cout << "\n"; 
    system("cls");
} 
//sortirovka
void gnomeSort(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    int index = 0; 
    while (index < n) { 
        if (index == 0)index++; 
        if (arr[index] >= arr[index - 1]){index++;}    
        else { 
            swap(arr[index], arr[index - 1]); 
            index--; printArray(arr, n); cout<<endl; 
        } 
    } 
    return; 
} 

//glavnaya funktsia
int main() 
{ 
    int arr[] = { 35, 2, 10, -9,4,23,423,45,6,89,68,45,88,72,4,6,8,3,2,4 }; 
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 

    gnomeSort(arr, n); 
    printArray(arr, n); 


    return (0); 
}
```

Comment: I don't know the `COLOR` command and on which console/OS you try to use it. However, wouldn't be the obvious solution to `system(COLOR C); std::cout << i; system(COLOR A);` where `C` is the other color and `A` is the default color?

Comment: Actually, I don't find colors important concerning console output. Instead, I find much more important that console output can be easily redirected e.g. into a file. Colors aren't useful for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ANSI_COLOR_RED     "\x1b[31m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_GREEN   "\x1b[32m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW  "\x1b[33m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BLUE    "\x1b[34m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA "\x1b[35m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_CYAN    "\x1b[36m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_RESET   "\x1b[0m"

int main (int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  printf(ANSI_COLOR_RED     "This text is RED!"     ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
  printf(ANSI_COLOR_GREEN   "This text is GREEN!"   ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
  printf(ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW  "This text is YELLOW!"  ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
  printf(ANSI_COLOR_BLUE    "This text is BLUE!"    ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
  printf(ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA "This text is MAGENTA!" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
  printf(ANSI_COLOR_CYAN    "This text is CYAN!"    ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");

  return 0;
}
```

More colors code [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors)

On Windows, (using windows.h header file)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>   // WinApi header

int main()
{
  HANDLE  hConsole;
    int k;

  hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

  // you can loop k higher to see more color choices
  for(k = 1; k < 255; k++)
  {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, k);
    printf("%3d  %s\n", k, "I want to be nice today!");
  }

  getchar();  // wait
  return 0;
}
```